# PySpark : What is difference between below two use of desc function in dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the difference between  `empDF["Last Name"].desc()` and `desc("Last Name")` as both are giving same result and both involved shuffle operation

```
>>> empDF.orderBy(empDF["Last Name"].desc()).show(4)
+------+----------+---------+------+------+
|Emp ID|First Name|Last Name|Gender|Salary|
+------+----------+---------+------+------+
|977421|   Zackary|  Zumwalt|     M|177521|
|741150|    Awilda|    Zuber|     F|144972|
|274620|  Eleanora|     Zook|     F|151026|
|242757|      Erin|     Zito|     F|127254|
+------+----------+---------+------+------+
only showing top 4 rows

>>> empDF.orderBy(desc("Last Name")).show(4)
+------+----------+---------+------+------+
|Emp ID|First Name|Last Name|Gender|Salary|
+------+----------+---------+------+------+
|977421|   Zackary|  Zumwalt|     M|177521|
|741150|    Awilda|    Zuber|     F|144972|
|274620|  Eleanora|     Zook|     F|151026|
|242757|      Erin|     Zito|     F|127254|
+------+----------+---------+------+------+
only showing top 4 rows
```

One thing  i noticed , to use desc() before column name i had to import `from pyspark.sql.functions import desc` . Is it like the former one is part of Spark Dataframe column function and later one is Spark SQL function ??? Is there any supporting doc or explanation for clarifying this confusion (i did not find any )???

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through Documentation  multipletimes  i understand now .There are two desc() available in pyspark.sql.* module . One is in `pyspark.sql.functions` module ([here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=read%20csv#pyspark.sql.functions.desc)) .
This method takes a mandatory column argument.
The Secnd one is inside `pyspark.sql.Column`  class ([here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column)). This one does not take any argument .

Both implementation do almost same thing and same way. But implementation is different and can be used interchangeably with proper import statement.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same thing.
As per documentation and source code (`funtions.desc..`)-

```scala
/**
   * Returns a sort expression based on the descending order of the column.
   * {{{
   *   df.sort(asc("dept"), desc("age"))
   * }}}
   *
   * @group sort_funcs
   * @since 1.3.0
   */
  def desc(columnName: String): Column = Column(columnName).desc
```

check internally `desc(columnName)` calls the `Column(columnName).desc` so both are same (take these as 2 alternatives performing the same operation)